# Yii2: How to add a CHECK CONSTRAINT to my model?

Tags: postgresql, model, yii2, check-constraints

I have a **CHECK CONTRAINT** of a table in my PostgreSQL database:

```
CHECK (since <= until)
```

**since** and **until** are dates.

I would like to add this constraint to my model but I don't know how to do it:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['since', 'until'], 'required'],
        [['since', 'until'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`CompareValidator`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-comparevalidator):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['since', 'until'], 'required'],
        [['since'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'util', 'operator' => '<='],
    ];
}
```

This will do string comparison and should work if you're using dates in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. In other case you need to convert dates to timestamp first:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['since', 'until'], 'required'],
        ['since', 'date', 'timestampAttribute' => 'since'],
        ['until', 'date', 'timestampAttribute' => 'until'],
        [['since'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'util', 'operator' => '<=', 'enableClientValidation' => false],
    ];
}
```

> The compare validator can only be used to compare strings and numbers.
>   If you need to compare values like dates you have two options. For
>   comparing a date against a fixed value, you can simply use the `date`
>   validator and specify its `$min` or `$max` property. If you need to
>   compare two dates entered in the form, e.g. a `fromDate` and a `toDate`
>   field, you can use a combination of compare and date validator like
>   the following:
>
> ```
> ['fromDate', 'date', 'timestampAttribute' => 'fromDate'],
> ['toDate', 'date', 'timestampAttribute' => 'toDate'],
> ['fromDate', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'toDate', 'operator' => '<', 'enableClientValidation' => false],
> ```
>
> As validators are executed in the order they are specified this will
>   first validate that the values entered in `fromDate` and `toDate` are
>   valid date values and if so, they will be converted into a machine
>   readable format. Afterwards these two values are compared with the
>   compare validator. Client validation is not enabled as this will only
>   work on the server-side because the date validator currently does not
>   provide client validation, so `$enableClientValidation` is set to `false`
>   on the compare validator too.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#comparing-date-values